# How do I forward Wii mail to another Wii?

Tags: nintendo-wii, homebrew

How do I forward mail that was sent to me in my Wii mail to another Wii?

I want to send LetterBomb to my friend's Wii without using a MAC address. I have all the files on an SD card for him, I just need the letter to be sent.

Comment: *Note: LetterBomb is a method to install [homebrew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_homebrew) on a Wii, apparently.*

Comment: That is certainly useful information. The question sounded like the asker was trying to spam the friend.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible; letterbomb works specifically on MAC addresses.  Forwarding a letterbomb isn't going to do the job, as it's tailored specifically to your Wii.

Comment: As a sidenote, I believe asking how to mod your console is allowed, as per http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/258/whats-the-official-stance-on-hacked-modded-consoles.

Comment: No offense, but my question wasn't answered at all...how do I forward wii mail? I want to forward homebrew to my friend.

Comment: As I had mentioned, I don't believe it's possible.  I'll do some testing tonight to see if any mail at all can be transferred.  If it can, I'll try punting over a letterbomb.  Doubt it'll work, though.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to forward mail from one Wii system to another.

If you want to use the LetterBomb exploit to install Homebrew onto a Wii, you will need the console's MAC Address. According to the [LetterBomb website](https://please.hackmii.com/), the MAC Address is "Necessary to create and sign the correct file".

A Wii's MAC Address can be found in the console settings. From the Main Menu, click the Wii Button, System Settings, navigate to page 2, click Internet, then select Console Information.

Comment: While Letterbomb won't work without the correct MAC Address, I thought it was possible to move/store/transfer mail onto the system SD card, then move the SD card to a different system?

Comment: @Robotnik I'm not aware of a method of transferring via SD card, but it could be a feature I'm unaware of.

Comment: I could also be mis-remembering, potentially. Will do some research once I'm off work.